# How to open and and close a small window in react passport auth flow

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

Currently I setup passport google authentication strategy in my react application login page... but when the user clicks authenticate by google they redirected to Google authentication page... 
How can I open a small window (or maybe iframe), instead of redirect user to Google authentication page and close that up when user successfully authenticate or process failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codeburst.io/react-authentication-with-twitter-google-facebook-and-github-862d59583105

Click on the linked solution: It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you're using any node module for this.

But I'd recommend using [**`firebaseui-web-react`**](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react) and installing:

```
npm install --save firebase react-firebaseui
```

Once that's done, it's pretty straight-forward. Here, give this a try:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";

// Styles
import styles from "./styles.css"; // This uses CSS modules.
import "./firebaseui-styling.global.css"; // Import globally.

// Get the Firebase config from the auto generated file.
const firebaseConfig = require("./firebase-config.json").result;

// Instantiate a Firebase app.
const firebaseApp =
  !firebase.apps.length && firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function FirebaseAuth(props) {
  const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false
    }
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isSignedIn: undefined
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const unregisterAuthObserver = firebaseApp
      .auth()
      .onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        setState({ isSignedIn: !!user });
      });

    return () => {
      unregisterAuthObserver();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.logo}>
        <i className={styles.logoIcon + " material-icons"}>photo</i> My App
      </div>
      <div className={styles.caption}>This is a cool demo app</div>
      {state.isSignedIn !== undefined && !state.isSignedIn && (
        <div>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth
            className={styles.firebaseUi}
            uiConfig={uiConfig}
            firebaseAuth={firebaseApp.auth()}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      {state.isSignedIn && (
        <div className={styles.signedIn}>
          Hello {firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.displayName}. You are now signed
          In!
          <a
            href="#"
            className={styles.button}
            onClick={() => firebaseApp.auth().signOut()}
          >
            Sign-out
          </a>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FirebaseAuth;
```

---

> Here's a [**Working CodeSandbox Sample**](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-platform-qd16e) for your ref.

---

**PS:** Since we'd be running this on CodeSandbox, we'll have to add the Domain of the generated CodeSandbox to the Authorized Domains Section by going to:

> Project in Console > Authentication > Sign-in Method > Authorized domains > Click **Add domain**

Comment: thanx for the answer, I actually using passport on the backend and just want that popup